# Why I cannot access some pages while I am the one who created them in ORACLE APEX?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-apex

I have a have a problem with ORACLE APEX, I created 7 interactive report pages, I can access 6 of them and the one the named ADMINS I can only view the table but when I try to edit it shows this error message:

```
Sorry, this page isn't available. 

Error process request. 

Contact your application administrator.
```

And same thing for Administration page, it shows the same error message when I try to access it.

Comment: are you the only person who has developer access? is it always same page(s)?

Comment: Turn on debug via developer toolbar and check the debug logs when this error occurs. That should give you information about why he error is happening

Comment: Also "while I am the one who created" does not make much sense - there are many conditions for a page to render (authorization scheme, build option, no error in any process) but who created the page is never a condition for rendering.